# How to set Checkbox status on WinForm in Visual Studio C# based on SQL database values?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to set checkboxes on a C# Windows Form in VS2017 to either checked or unchecked state, based on values retrieved from a corresponding SQL Server database.  I have been unable to set the checked property of checkboxes drawn on a Winform in VS2017 w/ corresponding values from a SQL Server table.

I have a C# Windows Form in Visual Studio that ties with a SQL database in SQL Server.  There are multiple checkboxes on this form that correspond w/ column names in the SQL database. The columns are datatype "bit" within SQL Server. 
 The Winform checkboxes are standalone checkboxes drawn onto the form.  I have attempted multiple approaches on what seems like a straightforward task, but have so far been unable to get the checkbox states to load.

*** SQL Server Info ***
The SQL SERVER database name is "Companies", the data table name is "Customers", and the specific column of interest is named "custNeed", which has a "bit" datatype.

`Companies.dbo.Customers.custNeed`

***VS2017 C# Info***

Below is my current C# code attempt for this method. This code is only for one specific checkbox.  This specific record has a value of 1 and the default check state is false in VS2017.

```
private void loadCheckMarks()
{
    //connect to SQL DB, then build adapter to fill datatable
    string query = "SELECT custNeed FROM Companies.dbo.Customers;";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
    connection.ConnectionString = connStr;
    connection.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    //establish reader
    SqlDataReader reader;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select custNeed FROM Customers WHERE ID = 1000001;";
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //set Checked status of Checkbox
    checkBox1.Checked = (bool)reader["custNeed"];
}
```

I called the method on a button click and expected the checkbox to change from unchecked to check, but nothing happened.

Comment: What do you see when you add a breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteReader();` and debug the code?

Comment: I don't see a `reader.Read();` after the ExecuteReader but that should also throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're defining the `cmd` but there's a lot going on here that has nothing to do with reading that query and setting a checkbox. Here is some simple code that uses the `ExecuteScalar` method since you are only requesting a single row and column. There is no error handling as the code is simply showing you a method for doing what you're asking. It will fail if you do not find a record based on your id and needs to be handled.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    string query = "SELECT custNeed FROM Customers WHERE ID = 1000001;";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        //since you're only returning a single column you can forego the reader 
        //and just use ExecuteScalar
        checkBox1.Checked = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Also, since you eluded to multiple checkboxes, I'll add a method which uses a reader to read through the returned row. Again, no error handling and using reader.Read(); to read an single row instead of looping through the reader.

While I don't fully know the schema of your Customers table, I'll just use a couple of column names as examples

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    string query = "SELECT custNeed, isActive FROM Customers WHERE ID = 1000001;";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read(); //reads the first single returned row. 
            checkBox1.Checked = (bool)reader["custNeed"];
            checkBox2.Checked = (bool)reader["isActive"];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Really appreciate the help!